# Ajuda para passar valores da tabela que esta dentro php via form

Tags: php

Ola amigos preciso de uma forca aqui seguinte:

Recebo uma tabela com os valores dentro do php preciso pegar a tabela completa e enviar atraves do form via post nao estou conseguindo enviar a tebela colocando ali no value o php

abaixo coloquei primeiro o codigo que recebo a tabela e logo mais abaixo esta o form

```html
<?php
$array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"]);

$total = 0;

// CABEÇALHO
echo '
  <table width="95%"  border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="26%"><div align="center">Nome</div></td>
      <td width="41%"><div align="center">Preco</div></td>
      <td width="33%"><div align="center">Quantidade</div></td>
    <td width="33%"><div align="center">Subtotal</div></td>
    </tr>';

foreach($array_dados as $obj)
{

 echo '
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->nome . '</div></td>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->preco . '</div></td>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->qtd . '</div></td>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->subtotal . '</div></td>
    </tr>';

    $total = $total + $obj->subtotal;
}

echo '
    <tr><td colspan="4"><div align="center">Total: '.$total.'</div></td></tr>
  </table>';

?>

    <form method="post" action="finaliza.php">
      
   <input type="hidden" name="tabela toda" value="AQUI_A_TABELA">
    
      <input type="submit" value="Finalizar Pedido">
      
    </form>
```

Comment: Você quer enviar cada linha dessa tabela tudo junto? Ou individual? E para onde quer enviar? Desta forma aí que você tá fazendo não dá certo nunca.

Comment: Tudo junto o que esta dentro do php quero colocar o valor ali no input !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particularmente não sei o que você quer fazer com isso, mas está aí uma solução abaixo. O `name` do seu campo `hidden` está incorreto. Não pode haver espaços. Dê uma olhada.

### PHP

```
<?php
    $array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"]);

    $total = 0;

    // CABEÇALHO
    $tabela_toda = '
    <table width="95%"  border="1" align="center">
       <tr>
          <td width="26%"><div align="center">Nome</div></td>
          <td width="41%"><div align="center">Preco</div></td>
          <td width="33%"><div align="center">Quantidade</div></td>
          <td width="33%"><div align="center">Subtotal</div></td>
       </tr>';

       foreach($array_dados as $obj)
       {

          $tabela_toda .= '
          <tr>
             <td><div align="center">'. $obj->nome . '</div></td>
             <td><div align="center">'. $obj->preco . '</div></td>
             <td><div align="center">'. $obj->qtd . '</div></td>
             <td><div align="center">'. $obj->subtotal . '</div></td>
          </tr>';

          $total = $total + $obj->subtotal;
       }

       $tabela_toda .= '
       <tr><td colspan="4"><div align="center">Total: '.$total.'</div></td></tr>
    </table>';

    echo $tabela_toda;
?>
```

### HTML

```
<form method="post" action="finaliza.php">

   <input type="hidden" name="tabela_toda" value="<?=$tabela_toda?>">

   <input type="submit" value="Finalizar Pedido">

</form>
```

Comment: Pro mais que eu coloque o input type="hidden"  ele fiCA exibe um pedaço da tabela e não envia

Comment: Não existe type=hidden. Hidden é declarado dentro das tags.

Comment: Envia por type=text e usa hidden dentro do campo input.

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro o que ? Claro que existe. http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden

Comment: @HemersonPrestes quando você enviar para o PHP faça: `echo  $_POST['tabela_toda'];` e veja o que acontece.